# Detecting if code is being run as a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working with some code that needs to be run as a page, and if it's being run as a [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/getstarted), I want to be able to do additional things. What I'm using is:

```
<script>
if (chrome && chrome.extension) {
    // extension stuff
}
</script>
```

This seems like a good [capability](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension) [detection](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/using-capability-detection/). Using user agent string causes me trouble because it's the same no matter the context (web page vs. extension).

Question: are there other more reliable techniques for detecting if a piece of code is running inside a Chrome extension?

**Update:** I'm wondering if there's something I can put into my [`manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest) file that I can then read back. Note, that the extension I'm working on is not intended as a persistent thing that runs all the time, it's a content application that runs in a single window or browser tab and has no need to interact with other windows or tabs or anything else.

Comment: You could try and get get internationalized strings, although checking for extension status is not its intended purpose: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So many complicated answers here, while you can easily detect whether you're running in a Chrome extension by checking for existence and non-emptiness of [`chrome.runtime.id`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-id):

```
if (window.chrome && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.id) {
    // Code running in a Chrome extension (content script, background page, etc.)
}
```

Comment: Excellent point. `chrome.runtime` was released as part of Chrome 22 ( https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-id ) released September 25, 2012 ( http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2012/09/stable-channel-update_25.html ) ... a year after the question and accepted answer were posted. I'm updating the accepted answer. 
Thanks for the exhumation!

Comment: in both cases, the condition is true, Either we check from inside the extension popup or in the browser page view.

Comment: Does it have an advantage over OP usage of `chrome && chrome.extension`?

Comment: @HeyJude Yes, it does! `chrome` is only publicly available in Chromium-based browsers. If you use `chrome &&`, you would get a runtime error when the script runs in a regular web page in a non-Chrome browser, such as Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Oh well, your're right of course, but besides that: does using `.runtime` has an advantage over `.extension`?

Comment: This worked great! Now I don't have to switch code around to test an Angular 10 Chrome extension (the popup.html script part)  as a browser extension as well as in a regular browser window using `ng serve`! Much more convenient to develop a browser extension UI in a normal browser window with auto-reloading.

Answer (score 8):

I had the need for something similar.

But I didn't need to care about sites attempting to trick the code.

```
const SCRIPT_TYPE = (() => {
    if (chrome && chrome.extension && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() === window) {
        return 'BACKGROUND';
    } else if (chrome && chrome.extension && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() !== window) {
        return 'POPUP';
    } else if (!chrome || !chrome.runtime || !chrome.runtime.onMessage) {
        return 'WEB';
    } else {
        return 'CONTENT';
    }
})();
```

The above should detect the 4 scenarios

- javascript is run in a background page
- javascript is run in a popup page / iframe
- javascript is run in a context script
- javascript is run in a directly on a website

Answer (score 5):

Pragmatically that's a good approach. Theoretically (not sure if this is relevant or not, e.g. may provide vulnerabilities) it can be spoofed very easily. I suppose it depends on your context how relevant that is.

Here's a slightly stronger idea:

```
if (chrome &&
    chrome.windows &&
    chrome.windows.get &&
    typeof chrome.windows.get === 'function' &&
    chrome.windows.get.toString() === 'function get() { [native code] }')
```

The idea is the same as yours, although it's slightly stronger, since AFAIK having an object be a function and having it's `toString()` value have that value is impossible since it's not valid syntax, so even trying to spoof that value wouldn't work unless you altered the native code (which requires a whole different level of hacker).

Don't offhand remember if checking things like this requires permissions or not, but the idea is clear I hope.

**UPDATE**

I just realised that the "native code" syntax idea can be fooled, by aliasing an existing function. E.g.

```
var FakeFn = Object.create;
FakeFn.toString(); // "function create() { [native code] }"
```

But that can be taken care of by careful selection of which function we use, since the name appears in the string. `get` is probably too common, but if we take an obscure function name (like `captureVisibleTab` of `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`) that is implemented only in chrome extensions, it is still a very portable solution, because unlike the basic check where code can be fooled by other local user code, it is known in advance that the browsers don't implement any native functions with this name, so it's still safe in all browsers and with all user code.

**UPDATE**

As @Mathew pointed out, this idea is foolable (although seemingly only maliciously). I thought I could patch the problem by comparing to `Function.prototype.toString` but figured that even that can be fooled by aliasing the original `toString` method and creating a new one that for certain functions returns false strings and for others returns the original string.

In conclusion, my idea is slightly stronger than the original, in that it will rule out practically all chance of unintentional collision (slightly more than the OP's idea), but is certainly no defence against a malicious attack as I first thought it might be.

Comment: Interesting, and works as expected, but I'm not convinced it's more portable than mine. I'm wondering if there's something I can put into my `manifest.json` file that I can then read back somehow. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: @artlung, any such approach is less portable than mine, let me explain: The entire extension API (AFAIK, I'm admittedly not very expert on the API) is javascript based. So all calls will conform with JS standards, and will take the regular `obj.ref.fn()` form, which by definition can be fooled. The reason my approach is more portable is because it cannot be fooled. You cannot create an object that passes those conditions unless you tamper with the browser itself, whereas I can easily create `window.chrome={extension:true}` in any browser and your code will think it's a chrome extension.

Comment: You make an excellent point. I think my intent is not to rigidly enforce non-spoofing, but simply to discriminate between simple usage of Chrome (and the many variants) and coded loaded as part of an extenson. Thank you VERY much for the careful thought put into this!

Comment: Something like that would work, but it's still not a guarantee. Someone could just do this: `chrome = { windows: { get: function() {} } }; chrome.windows.get.toString = function() { return 'function get() { [native code] }' };`. Of course, they would essentially have to do it on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but just thought I'd offer an alternative.  You can add another javascript file to the chrome extension, so it contains two .js files.  manifest.json would have:

```
"js": ["additionalscript.js", "yourscript.js"]
```

The additionalscript.js could simply declare a variable `var isextension = true`.  yourscript.js can check `typeof isextension != 'undefined'`.

But perhaps a more interesting example, it could declare

```
var adminpassword='letmein'
```

Now yourscript.js only has access to adminpassword when running in the extension.

(Of course you would not embed a password in a script file if the plugin were on a machine that could be compromised)

Comment: I think you mean 'scripts' not 'js'. You would always want to do the test as `typeof isextension != 'undefined'` or you will get an JavaScript exception when additionalscript.js wasn't executed. You should also note that this is in the 'background' section of the manifest.

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGrath - I have a "content_scripts" section of the manifest.json that has a "js" entry:  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js" :["One.js", "Two.js"]
    }
  ].  And good point re checking for undefined

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in Chrome, the chrome object, that is property of the global window object, could not be deleted. If it is user-defined property delete operation is successful. So you could test in this way:

```
var isRunningInExtension = (!(delete window.chrome) && chrome.extension) ? 
                           true : false;
```

UPDATE:
Line above does not really guarantee that code is running in chrome extension. Everyone can create an object called 'chrome' with an 'extension' property and then freeze/seal that object - doing this will be enough to pass the check and have an incorrect result that your code is running inside a chrome extension.

The ensure you are running your code in an extension, you have to test the global chrome object before any javascript to be run - that way you will have guarantee that no fake chrome object is created before testing.

One possible solution is to use an iframe - in my example below i use iframe's sandbox property to instruct the iframe not to execute any scripts(even scripts included with script tag) - in that way i can ensure no script will be able to modify the global window.chrome object.

```
(function() {
  var isChromeExtension = (function () {
    var contentWindow,
        iframe = document.createElement("iframe"),
        isChromeExtension;
    // test for sandbox support. It is supported in most recent version of Chrome
    if ("sandbox" in iframe) {
      try {
        iframe.sandbox = "allow-same-origin";
        iframe.src=location.href;
        iframe.style="display: none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        contentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
        isChromeExtension = !!(contentWindow.chrome && contentWindow.chrome.extension);
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
      } catch(e) {}
    }
    return isChromeExtension;
  }());
}());
```

result could be:

- true - if code is running inside an extension of Chrome
- false - if code is not running inside an extension of Chrome
- undefined - if browser does not support sandbox for iframes or some error happened during test

Comment: It's not clear to me that your understanding of how `delete` works is as you say. I can also create an object, say `window.g = {x:1}` and run delete on it and get similar result of false when trying to delete it. ... maybe a fuller example of this working is needed.

Comment: Your new method is not very performant, and not fool-proof either. If the environment is really malicious, then any object, including the `document` can be spoofed. There is no way to defend against that, so you should instead go for the most readable and straightforward method.

Comment: It's not very performant indeed - it loads the whole page/styles/scripts into the iframe, but none of the scripts will be executed(inline or included with script tag) - that's the role of the sandbox - so there's no way from the client side to change the global objects and even to imitate the document object.

Keep in mind that chrome object can NOT be deleted, but everyone can override it - so, i can do the following:

`window.chrome = {runtime: {id: {}}};` and your suggested answer will say that my code is running inside an extension, while that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not provide any direct API to check the running status of the application that is it running in extension popup or in chrome page view. however, One indirect trick can work is we can match the extension body resolution that is equal or less than as specified in CSS (in this case, extension popup will be open) or greater than that (in this case, web page view will be open).

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [`Chad Scira`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310299/551625) for the original answer mine is based of.

---

I grabbed Chad's answer and I compacted it to ES2021 standards. Removed a lot of repeated content required for previous versions too.

```
const runningAt = (() => {
    let getBackgroundPage = chrome?.extension?.getBackgroundPage;
    if (getBackgroundPage){
        return getBackgroundPage() === window ? 'BACKGROUND' : 'POPUP';
    }
    return chrome?.runtime?.onMessage ? 'CONTENT' : 'WEB';
})();
```

The above should detect the 4 scenarios

- javascript is run in a background page
- javascript is run in a popup page / iframe
- javascript is run in a context script
- javascript is run in a directly on a website

Answer (score 0):

To detect chrome apps and extensions use:

```
chrome.app.getDetails()
```

Comment: Not exactly what the question asked for. And exception if run the code on other browsers.